# Passing parameters to multiple screens in the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm sending some data through my nested navigators. I've got 2 screens on my tab navigator `QR kod` and `eINFO`. I'm passing my data to `qr kod` here

```js
      navigation.navigate("Drawer", {
        screen: "Home",
        params: {
          screen: "QR kod",
          params: { user: newUser },
        },
      });
```

these are my navigators

```js
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({route}) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
          let iconName;

          if (route.name === 'QR kod') {
            iconName = focused ? 'qrcode' : 'qrcode';
          } else if (route.name === 'eINFO') {
            iconName = focused ? 'infocirlceo' : 'infocirlceo';
          }

          return <AntDesign name={iconName} size={24} color={'black'} />;
        },
      })}
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: 'red',
        inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="QR kod" component={Main} />
      <Tab.Screen name="eINFO" component={Einfo} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function DrawerNav() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="QR kod">
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={TabNavigation} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

How do I pass the data to both `eINFO` and `QR kod` at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, unfortunately if you are using `navigation.navigate` to pass data to `qr kod` screen, you cannot pass same data to `eINFO` screen at the same time. If you want to have the same data in both screens at the same time my suggest is to use a global state manager like [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/). With react-redux you don't need to pass data between screens with `navigation.navigate` anymore. Just dispatch data you need to redux store and then read data dispatched in any screen you need.

Comment: Marking this as a solution. Implemented Redux which worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the initialParams prop on your tabs may work. It's useful to pass params to child screens automatically.

```
function Home(props) {
  const params = props.route.params;
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({route}) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
          let iconName;
          ...
    }>
      <Tab.Screen name="QR kod" component={Main} initialParams={params} />
      <Tab.Screen name="eINFO" component={Einfo} initialParams={params} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Then your `user` param will be passed to both screens.

Change your navigate call to:

```
navigation.navigate("Drawer", {
  screen: "Home",
  params: {
    screen: "QR kod",
    user: newUser,
  },
});
```

I'm not sure exactly how your data flow is structured from what you have posted. Usually however, something like 'user data' is best handled by Redux as Giovanni Esposito said.