# How to propagate react navigation params to multiple Screens sharing the same Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to work with the react-native and react-navigation library. I'm trying to pass a param to multiple screens sharing the same Tab Navigator.

This is the scenery:

App.js

```js
const MainScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <Button
      onPress={() =>
        navigation.navigate("User", { prop_i_want_to_share: "asd" })
      } //This is the param I would like to share
    />
  );
};

const UserInfoScreen = ({ route }) => (
  <View>
    {route.params.prop_i_want_to_share} // Here I would like to get the param used in navigation
  </View>
);

const UserEditScreen = ({ route }) => (
  <View>
    {route.params.prop_i_want_to_share} // Here I would like to get the param used in navigation
  </View>
);

const UserTab = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="UserInfo" component={UserInfoScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="UserEdit" component={UserEditScreen} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
);

render() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="User" component={UserTab} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to propagate the params, but I think I didn't design properly the navigator structure and that's why I'm finding this issue. What would you change to make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer for this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63064798/13315676).

Depending on what version of react-navigation you're using (I'll assume 6.x), to pass to a nested navigator you could use:

In MainScreen

```
navigation.navigate('User', {
  screen: 'UserInfo',
  params: { prop_i_want_to_share: "asd" },
});
```

Then you can pass the param to the next screen once you navigate to it:

In UserInfoScreen

```
navigation.navigate('User', {
  screen: 'UserEdit',
  params: { prop_i_want_to_share: route.params.prop_i_want_to_share },
});
```

But if you're trying to update a global variable, that is a variable that gets used in multiple screens (ex: CurrentlyLoggedInUserId), you might not want to use params at all. You could use a [state management tool](https://dev.to/workshub/state-management-battle-in-react-2021-hooks-redux-and-recoil-2am0) like Recoil, Redux, React's useContext or even create your own custom hook.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it yet, but with latest v6, you can use [Groups](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/group/#props):

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Group screenOptions={({ route, navigation }) => ({ prop_i_want_to_share: 'asd' })}>  
    {/* screens */}
  </Stack.Group>
</Stack.Navigator>
```